# No way to resolve conflict between - Warning

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, conflicting-libraries

I am given such a warning during visual studio building

```
7>  No way to resolve conflict between "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60". Choosing "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" arbitrarily.
```

In the solution I have several projects. How can I know / find where the compiler's confusion comes from?
I was looking everywhere in the solution and I see no assembly in any project where can be used version 2.0.0.0?

Comment: Presumably some library you reference us using the newer version.

Comment: You may look at transitive dependencies in your projects, some of your libraries can use newer or older version of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Comment: 1. Check the dependencies of your dependencies, 2. I recommend injecting dependencies via constructors (both as objects for single instances and as factory functions for places where you need to create instances in scope) instead of using a DI library.

Comment: @John, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This may be caused the two nuget package's dependencies which contain the same dependency `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` but different versions. Or it is the project reference's dll.

Like this:

[image]

One way is to install `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` nuget package version `3.0.0`.

Or add `bindingRedirect` under `xxx.config` file:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" publicKeyToken="xxx" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

**2)** or just find the issue nuget and then update the its version which uses `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 3.0.0` dependencies.

**3)** Or you could use [PackageReference nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files). This is a new nuget management format. Right-click on the `packages.config` file-->**Migrate packages.config into PackageReference**.

**Besides**, if the issue still persists, you could share the `packages.config` with us to help us troubleshoot the issue in our side.